# Koloda Tinder Swiping Swift 3.0

Tags: swift3, koloda

It was working well on the swift 2.2 version but when upgraded to the 3.0 branch I had issues with my datasource and delegate being alloc to the same part of memory. Screenshot is attached to show issue. Any reasons to why this is happening?

[image]